# How to normalise all training samples at once using MinMaxScaler

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I have 1320 training samples (sea surface temperature) and each sample is a 2d array(160,320) so the final array is in the shape (1320,160,320). I would like to normalize them to values between 0 and 1 using MinMaxScaler(). I get the error "Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2.". My code is as follows. I could loop through all the 1320 samples, normalising them one by one but I would like to know if there is a way to normalize all of them because Max and Mix for each sample is not the same.

```
scaler = prep.MinMaxScaler()
sst = scaler.fit_transform(sst)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't really do it only using MinMaxScaler(). `np.apply_along_axis` won't be useful either since you want to apply a min-max scaler over 2D slices. One solution could be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((2, 3, 3))

def customMinMaxScaler(X):
    return (X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min())

np.array([customMinMaxScaler(x) for x in a])
```

But I guess it wouldn't be much faster than iterating over the samples.

Comment: Don't forget that the scaler needs to store min and max so it always uses the same min-max values for different parts (e.g. train & test) of the same dataset. I guess the intuition of not allowing 3 dimensions is because they assume the data to have the shape (samples, features). They scale per each feature so all channels are mapped from their own data range to the range (0, 1); In my case I've struggled because I got the shape (samples, timestamps, features) but with the previously collected knowledge I assume that you need to merge samples and timestamps and split it again afterwards.